# How can I draw the bounds of any 3d object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a cube/box I did:

```
void CalcPositons(GameObject objectToDrawTransform)
    {
        Bounds bounds = objectToDrawTransform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds;

        Vector3 v3Center = bounds.center;
        Vector3 v3Extents = bounds.extents;

        v3FrontTopLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front top left corner
        v3FrontTopRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front top right corner
        v3FrontBottomLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front bottom left corner
        v3FrontBottomRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front bottom right corner
        v3BackTopLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back top left corner
        v3BackTopRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back top right corner
        v3BackBottomLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back bottom left corner
        v3BackBottomRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back bottom right corner

        v3FrontTopLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontTopLeft);
        v3FrontTopRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontTopRight);
        v3FrontBottomLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontBottomLeft);
        v3FrontBottomRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontBottomRight);
        v3BackTopLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackTopLeft);
        v3BackTopRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackTopRight);
        v3BackBottomLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackBottomLeft);
        v3BackBottomRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackBottomRight);
    }
```

Then I'm using a LineRenderer to draw the lines.
I don't want to make outline shader.

Now I created a script for a test:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objecttodraw;

    private void Start()
    {
        CalcPositons(objecttodraw);
    }

    void CalcPositons(GameObject objectToDrawTransform)
    {
        Bounds bounds = objectToDrawTransform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds;

        Vector3 v3Center = bounds.center;
        Vector3 v3Extents = bounds.extents;
    }
}
```

And this is the 3d object the script is attached to and the object that I want to get the bounds of:

[image: bounds]

I'm getting the Center and the Extents but how do I draw now the bounds ?

Comment: According to your code what you are trying to do is make an outline of the MeshFilter. Am I correct?

Comment: @SharadKhanna This is the idea to get and draw the outline of the object/s. I used before a shader and it was working fine , I just wonder if there is a way to do it without a shader ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will have to create a GameObject that surrounds the thing you want to surround. Then it just gets more complicated, I highly recommend you use a shader instead.

Comment: Is the goal to show a bounding box in the editor, or in the game at runtime?